# How to sort files by list elements by date modified, in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list something like the following:

```
[{'modified': 'Thu, 08 Aug 2013 18:28:13 +0000', 'path': '/test4.txt'},
 {'modified': 'Thu, 06 Aug 2013 18:28:17 +0000', 'path': '/test5.txt'},
 ...
]
```

and so on.
I want to sort the list by 'modified', in chronological (or reverse chronological) order What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort function needs to understand the dates first, else it will just sort by the letters of the weekday.

The [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package is perfect for this task. It will automatically identify the date and doesn't require a format string like `datetime.strptime`.

```
from dateutil import parser

# sort ascending
print sorted(yourlist, key=lambda k: parser.parse(k['modified']))

# sort descending
print sorted(yourlist, key=lambda k: parser.parse(k['modified']), reverse=True)
```

Comment: +1 for figuring out that dates should not be sorted alphabetically. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
strfmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000'
res = sorted(files, key=lambda e: datetime.strptime(e['modified'], strfmt))
```

For the reverse, use the optional boolean `reverse` argument:

```
rev = sorted(files, key=..., reverse=True)
```

See [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) for more information.

Comment: `sorted(...)` takes in a `reverse` argument, no need to slice the list. :)

Comment: +1 for using `strptime`. Although, you should not use `format` as a variable name, since there is a built in function of that name.

Answer (score -1):

Use the "key" argument for [python's sorted function](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html).  If you really want chronological order, you'll also have to parse the date strings somehow.  I used datetime below (can't seem to get it to handle the time zone correctly):

import datetime as dt

list = [{'modified': 'Thu, 08 Aug 2013 18:28:13 +0000', 'path': '/test4.txt'}, {'modified': 'Thu, 06 Aug 2013 18:28:17 +0000', 'path': '/test5.txt'}]

list.sort(key=lambda d:dt.datetime.strptime(d['modified'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000'))

print list

output:

```
[{'path': '/test5.txt', 'modified': 'Thu, 06 Aug 2013 18:28:17 +0000'}, {'path': '/test4.txt', 'modified': 'Thu, 08 Aug 2013 18:28:13 +0000'}]
```